# adding ephemeral mount partition

Tags: amazon-ec2

When I launch m1.small I expect 160 GB instance storage. But I do not see that once I log in.

```
[root@ip-10-98-182-214 ec2-user]# df -HP
Filesystem             Size   Used  Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvde1             6.4G   2.9G   3.5G  45% /
none                   868M      0   868M   0% /dev/shm
```

Last time when I checked I used to get /mnt/ partition with enough storage. Ephemeral disk is good for testing purpose. I do not want to attach EBS volume.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you will need to enable this at launch. Some AMI's enable it by default, but not all of them will.

There is no way to add Ephemeral storage after the instance has launched.